# Apache nifi is not starting up

Tags: startup, apache-nifi

I am trying to start Apache nifi version 1.2.0 on window 8 machine. It used to start properly. After I restarted the system the nifi is not starting at all. I had check status Its keep getting "Apacha Nifi not running".

Below are logs from nifi.bootstrap.log file:-

```
2017-07-05 15:41:57,105 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the 
owner can read pid file E:\softwares\nifi-1.2.0\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this 
may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. 
Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2017-07-05 15:41:57,142 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the 
owner can read status file E:\softwares\nifi-1.2.0\bin\..\run\nifi.status; 
this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with 
NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this 
file
2017-07-05 15:41:57,168 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for 
Bootstrap requests on port 50765
2017-07-05 15:43:12,077 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr 
Failed to start web server: Unable to start Flow Controller.
2017-07-05 15:43:12,078 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr 
Shutting down...
2017-07-05 15:43:14,501 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi 
never started. Will not restart NiFi
```

Stack trace from nifi.app.log: -

```
2017-07-05 15:43:12,077 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:695)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:160)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:267)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected to read a Sentinel Byte of '1' but got a value of '0' instead
    at org.apache.nifi.repository.schema.SchemaRecordReader.readRecord(SchemaRecordReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.SchemaRepositoryRecordSerde.deserializeRecord(SchemaRepositoryRecordSerde.java:115)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.SchemaRepositoryRecordSerde.deserializeEdit(SchemaRepositoryRecordSerde.java:109)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.SchemaRepositoryRecordSerde.deserializeEdit(SchemaRepositoryRecordSerde.java:46)
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.recoverNextTransaction(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:1096)
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverFromEdits(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:459)
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverRecords(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:301)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.loadFlowFiles(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:381)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.initializeFlow(FlowController.java:712)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.initializeController(StandardFlowService.java:953)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:534)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:72)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Googling on this error "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected to read a Sentinel Byte of '1' but got a value of '0' instead" I found that this error indicates a partial write to the repos.

Here are a couple of things you can check/try to bring your Dataflow back online ;

- check if your dsks are not full
- Did you launch nifi with the same user ? Did you run it with administrator privileges ?
- You can backup/move your repositories and try to start Nifi with empty repositories, you will still have your dataflows there but any file that was processing when you shutdown will be gone.

Could you please try that ?

Comment: Hi Christophe thanks  You were right the last suggestion worked for me.

Comment: I deleted the repository folders but still unable to start the ni-fi instance. here is my query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364642/apache-nifi-not-able-to-start-ni-fi-instance

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with incompatible java version, use JAVA 8 version.

If you haven't set JAVA_HOME then set in environment variables with path Like "C:/program files/jdk1.8"

Jira addressing when NiFi run with java 9 version and the issue not resolved yet

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4419