# Apache Nifi - Not able to start Ni-Fi Instance

Tags: java, spring, apache-nifi

Whenever I execute run-nifi command,**I am not able to start my nifi instance**  as I am getting the java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException**
```

I am not sure why I am getting EOF exception as I am not reading any files.

I tried to delete the **content_repository,database_repository,flowfile_repository,provenance_repository**, tried changing the port number & restarted the PC but still unable to start the Ni-Fi instance.

I am affraid that all my saved workflow in Ni-Fi is gone.

Here is the complete Exception detail:

```
    org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:953)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:918)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:935)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:158)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:72)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:297)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:55)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
        at org.apache.nifi.spring.StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.getObject(StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.java:48)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
        ... 44 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:481)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.createStandaloneInstance(FlowController.java:367)
        at org.apache.nifi.spring.FlowControllerFactoryBean.getObject(FlowControllerFactoryBean.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
        ... 51 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.StateMapSerDe.deserializeRecord(StateMapSerDe.java:74)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.StateMapSerDe.deserializeRecord(StateMapSerDe.java:30)
        at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverFromSnapshot(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:386)
        at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverRecords(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:306)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.local.WriteAheadLocalStateProvider.init(WriteAheadLocalStateProvider.java:133)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.AbstractStateProvider.initialize(AbstractStateProvider.java:34)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider$1.initialize(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:267)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider.createStateProvider(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:206)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider.createLocalStateProvider(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:95)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.manager.StandardStateManagerProvider.create(StandardStateManagerProvider.java:79)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:479)
        ... 54 common frames omitted
    2019-12-16 16:06:26,060 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
    2019-12-16 16:06:26,068 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@3df2f4ab{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8015}
    2019-12-16 16:06:26,069 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node0 Stopped scavenging
```

Any leads on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Seems something with your flow.xml.gz

Comment: nope flow.xml.gz seems fine.

Comment: what about `./state/local` ?