# Nifi is NOT starting up after the VM restart

Tags: java, apache-nifi, startup

Nifi version 1.19.0 was working fine in our VM until the VM had to be restarted due to a suspension of our cloud provider account.
Post this the contents of the VM were replicated exactly using the snapshot of the VM.
After this nifi is failing to start with error in the logs:

> enter c2023-06-07 04:24:19,502 WARN [main]
> org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server...
> shutting down. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid nifi.web.https
> configuration in nifi.properties
> at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:89)
> at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.configureConnectors(JettyServer.java:738)
> at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.init(JettyServer.java:207)
> at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.initialize(JettyServer.java:1072)
> at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:164)
> at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:83)
> at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332) Caused by: org.apache.nifi.security.util.TlsException: The truststore properties
> are not valid
> at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.getTrustManagers(SslContextFactory.java:181)
> at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.createSslContext(SslContextFactory.java:67)
> at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:86)
> ... 6 common frames omitted 2023-06-07 04:24:19,503 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown startedode
> here

Things we have already checked:

1. If there is any other application running in the same port as 8443.
2. We emptied the content and provenance repos as mentioned in:[Apache nifi is not starting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924289/apache-nifi-is-not-starting-up)
3. We changed the java version to 8 from 11.
4. We tried to reboot nifi from a working flow.xml.gz and flow.json from a different machine.
5. Tried to restart with a completely new nifi installation folder.

However, so far I am getting the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error log you posted indicates that Apache NiFi failed to start due to an issue with the `nifi.web.https` configuration in `nifi.properties`. More specifically, the error message states, "The truststore properties are not valid", which suggests a problem with the truststore configuration.

NiFi uses the truststore and keystore for its HTTPS configuration. The truststore contains certificates from other parties that NiFi should trust, while the keystore contains the private and public key for NiFi itself.

Here are a few things you can check:

1. **Check the path and password**: Verify the truststore path and password in your `nifi.properties` file. The entries should look something like this:

   ```
   nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
   nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
   nifi.security.truststorePasswd=yourTrustStorePassword
   ```

   Make sure the path points to the correct file and the password is correct.
2. **Check the truststore file**: Confirm that your truststore file (e.g., `truststore.jks`) exists and is accessible. The path should be reachable from NiFi's point of view, and the file should have the correct permissions.
3. **Confirm the truststore type**: NiFi supports multiple types of truststore files, such as JKS, PKCS12, and others. Make sure the truststore type specified in the properties file matches the actual type of the truststore file.
4. **Ensure the truststore is not corrupted**: Try opening the truststore with a tool like `keytool` or `Keystore Explorer` to ensure it's not corrupted.
5. **Verify certificates**: Ensure the truststore contains the necessary certificates. This error can occur if the truststore doesn't include the appropriate trusted certificates.

In short, this error suggests a problem with the truststore setup. Verify your truststore file, its path, its password, and its contents to resolve this error.

I would also recommend that you do an audit of your Apache Nifi infrastructure as per this recent Malware warning : https://www.scmagazine.com/brief/cybercrime/apache-nifi-targeted-in-cryptomining-attacks